# Debian: Oracle Java 9 (JDK9) - Unable to locate package

Tags: debian, java

I want to install Oracle Java 9 (JDK9) on Debian.
I read [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2015/02/install-oracle-java-9-in-ubuntu-linux.html.)

when i try

```
apt-get install oracle-java9-installer
```

I have this error:

```
E: Unable to locate package oracle-java9-installer
```

i tried to solve my problem by:

```
add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
```

but i get this error :

```
add-apt-repository: command not found
```

for solving this problem i read [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45879/how-to-add-repository-from-shell-in-debian) and i tried

```
apt-get install python-software-properties
```

and

```
apt-get install software-properties-common
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer:

I just forgot to add

```
apt-get update
```

Answer (score 1):

I get the following update while adding PPA -

> Update: Oracle Java 9 has reached end of life: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk9-downloads-3848520.html

and I am not able to locate the package even after `apt-get update`. So I am guessing it is no longer available for install. So go over latest SE version.

Full text -

```
aniket@aniket-Compaq-610:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
[sudo] password for aniket: 
 Oracle Java (JDK) Installer (automatically downloads and installs Oracle JDK8). There are no actual Java files in this PPA.

Important -> Why Oracle Java 7 And 6 Installers No Longer Work: http://www.webupd8.org/2017/06/why-oracle-java-7-and-6-installers-no.html

Update: Oracle Java 9 has reached end of life: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk9-downloads-3848520.html

The PPA supports Ubuntu 18.10, 18.04, 16.04, 14.04 and 12.04.
```